# Extending a package/library class with fields and methods

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget-package

I've been developing some projects with `.NET` and right now I'm working to find a way to reduce the amount of code needed each time I start a new project.

I've created a nuget package to handle the authentication. Every time I start a new project, I only need to import that package, call the `load_config` function, and authentication works.

Now I'm attempting to find a way to create extensions to this package. For example, I would like to have a bunch of other private nuget packages that, when added to the project, would add more methods/fields to the classes of that package.

For example:

- Package `Authentication` - I have the class `BaseUser` with the required fields to authenticate (`Id`, `Name`, `password`, `tokens`, etc.)
- Package `Authentication.SocialProviders` - I have the required fields and methods to integrate social login (facebook, google, so on). It should extend the **`BaseUser` Class**
- Package `Addresses` - Extend the `BaseUser` class, adding two new fields to it (`BillingAddress`, `ShippingAddress`) and respective methods to manage those data
- Package `Messages` - Extend the `BaseUser` class, adding more fields and methods to the `BaseUser` class

In some projects I want my **final** `User` class to extend `Authentication` + `SocialProviders` + `Addresses`, while in others I would want all four. For this reason, the packages can't extend each other directly. Is there a way to implement what I'm looking for?

Comment: What about interfaces and extension methods? Have interfaces for Authentication, SocialProviders and Addresses that specify the fields. Implement logic for your interfaces in extension methods. That way you can implement any combination of interfaces you want.

Comment: And you might want to give partial class a try, which is also sort of LEGO like but in source code level rather than in nuget pkg level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `User` class that conditionally inherits from up to 4 different classes: `Authentication`, `SocialProviders`, `Addresses`, and `Messages`.

This isn't really how inheritance is designed to work. Inheritance generally denotes an "is - a" relationship between classes. The proper way to do what you want is with [composition](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/inheritance-vs-composition/) or [factory classes](https://betterprogramming.pub/5-ways-to-implement-factory-design-pattern-in-c-382c0992a3ff).

1. Composition: Have separate interfaces/classes for `Authentication`, `SocialProviders`, `Addresses`, and `Messages`. Have your class contain members for each interface you want and use a configuration to decide which classes are present. Composition can be denoted as being an "as a part" or "has a" relationship between classes.

```
public class Authentication
{
    // ...
}

public class SocialProviders
{
    // ...
}

public class Addresses
{
    // ...
}

public class Messages
{
    // ...
}

public class User
{
    private Authentication authentication = new Authentication();
    private SocialProviders sp = new SocialProviders();
    private Addresses addresses = new Addresses();
    private Messages messages = new Messages ();
    // ...
}
```

2. Factory: Have a factory class that makes the `User` objects on demand and gives them the appropriate sub-classes upon creation. This example shows one way to accomplish this, I'll adapt it to your use case if I have time later. Notice that `Resume` and `Report` both use factories and can contain any number/combination of the `Page` classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace DoFactory.GangOfFour.Factory.RealWorld
{
    class MainApp
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Note: constructors call Factory Method
            Document[] documents = new Document[2];
            documents[0] = new Resume();
            documents[1] = new Report();
            // Display document pages
            foreach (Document document in documents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + document.GetType().Name + "--");
                foreach (Page page in document.Pages)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" " + page.GetType().Name);
                }
            }
            // Wait for user
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    abstract class Page {}
   
    class SkillsPage : Page {}
    class EducationPage : Page {}
    class ExperiencePage : Page {}
    class IntroductionPage : Page {}
    class ResultsPage : Page {}
    class ConclusionPage : Page {}
    class SummaryPage : Page {}
    class BibliographyPage : Page {}
   
    abstract class Document
    {
        private List<Page> _pages = new List<Page>();
        // Constructor calls abstract Factory method
        public Document()
        {
            this.CreatePages();
        }
        public List<Page> Pages
        {
            get { return _pages; }
        }
        // Factory Method
        public abstract void CreatePages();
    }

    class Resume : Document
    {
        // Factory Method implementation
        public override void CreatePages()
        {
            Pages.Add(new SkillsPage());
            Pages.Add(new EducationPage());
            Pages.Add(new ExperiencePage());
        }
    }

    class Report : Document
    {
        // Factory Method implementation
        public override void CreatePages()
        {
            Pages.Add(new IntroductionPage());
            Pages.Add(new ResultsPage());
            Pages.Add(new ConclusionPage());
            Pages.Add(new SummaryPage());
            Pages.Add(new BibliographyPage());
        }
    }
}
```